# Emacs mmm-mode not highlighting a ruby submode (ERB) without a newline? Elisp advice?

Tags: ruby, emacs, elisp

I'm trying to get ERB templates 'working' in Emacs 22 and 23 (two different servers).

I've found several examples online that use almost exactly this snippet.  Note that I don't want any background colors, as I'm working in a terminal over SSH.

This is correctly detecting where the first region begins, as the mode line changes when the point moves.  But something is not right, since it doesn't highlight my ruby code unless I clear it with at least two blank lines, and it also seems to consider everything below the first segment of ruby code to be ruby code, even after the closing tags.

I can only assume that the patterns are not correct, and I'd like to understand the syntax so I can debug it better myself.  Can anyone tell me what all the `@` symbols mean here?

Moreover, has anybody actually gotten ERB templates working in mmm-mode?

```
(require 'mmm-mode)
(require 'mmm-auto) 

(setq mmm-global-mode 'maybe)
(setq mmm-submode-decoration-level 0)

(mmm-add-group
 'fancy-html
 '((html-erb
    :submode ruby-mode
    :match-face (("<%#" . mmm-comment-submode-face)
                 ("<%=" . mmm-output-submode-face)
                 ("<%"  . mmm-code-submode-face))
    :front "<%[#=]?"
    :back "%>"
    :insert ((?% erb-code       nil @ "<%"  @ " " _ " " @ "%>" @)
             (?# erb-comment    nil @ "<%#" @ " " _ " " @ "%>" @)
             (?= erb-expression nil @ "<%=" @ " " _ " " @ "%>" @)))))

(add-to-list 'mmm-mode-ext-classes-alist '(html-mode nil fancy-html))
```

[image: Ruby detected but not highlighted]
[image: Ruby highlighted, but rest of buffer broken]

Comment: Note that this is emacs 22. It doesn't seem to work at all in emacs 23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have [a similar setup](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/init-ruby-mode.el#L45), which might even have been the basis for what you're trying. Executing `font-lock-fontify-buffer` even with the newlines missing causes the correct highlighting to be displayed, so the problem presumably lies in mmm-mode.

The main benefit of the `mmm-mode` setup has been that I can easily see the ERB regions; the setup has never syntax-highlighted embedded code perfectly for me, and although I've been [updating `mmm-mode` for compatibility with recent emacsen](https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode), it might be worth you exploring alternatives if you really want that detailed sub-region highlighting.

Like you, I've been unwilling to resort to `nxhtml` because it's very heavy-weight, and I believe it also has display quirks.

I'll also point out that `haml-mode` does quite a nice job of syntax-highlighting embedded code blocks natively (just ruby code originally, until I contributed javascript and css support), and that's one of several reasons why I prefer haml to html+erb these days.

Comment: Currently installing your .emacs.d.  I'm a new emacs user (2 weeks-ish) and my customizations have been very much hack and slash.  I need to learn elisp.  Emacs is currently "doing something", but I'll post back and let you know how I go.  If emacs behaves even half as annoyingly with regards to indentation and syntax highlighting I'll be very happy! Thanks so much for sharing.

Comment: "Symbol's function definition is void: string-prefix-p" https://gist.github.com/1239395. Any ideas what I need to do to get past this? Using emacs 23 from Ubuntu 10.04 package manager.

Comment: Installed emacs 23.3 (was on 23.1) and it's working. This is awesome. So many goodies. Thank you.

Comment: Great. Let me know how you get on. I guess `string-prefix-p` was added after 23.1. I'll patch that if I get around to it.

Comment: What makes nxhtml "very heavy weight"?  It adds 0.5s to my Emacs start-up, and I haven't noticed any display issues.  I had to jump through some hoops to install it the first time, but recently I've switched to using John Wigeley's github mirror and updates are painless.

Comment: IIRC, nxhtml and all the trimmings weighed in at something silly like 70mb when I looked into it a couple of years ago. The runtime behaviour might be okay, though, and to be fair, I should give it another go. Thanks for the pointer to John's mirror.

Comment: Just a comment for posterity's sake.  As of now, the latest version of nhxmlt is just a pile of headaches.  I'm trying to find a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you have SSH access to the box, use tramp.

I have no deep MMM-mode magic for ERB.  However, I use Rinari with nxhtml and it all just works.  Ask questions about rinari and nxhtml if you need help getting that going.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give MuMaMo a go.  That's last on my list to try (looked a bit bloated).  I've already tried multi-web-mode and mmm-mode.  AFAIK, nxhtml/MuMaMo is the only other alternative available.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed now. Update to the latest mmm-mode from [git repo](https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode) or [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/).

Comment: Dmitry, do I understand correctly that it should highlight ruby in <%%> blocks now? Because it doesn't work for me (neither from melpa nor from git)

Comment: It should, as long as you set up the submode classes properly. The example in this question looks all right, but I'm not sure about the `nil`s in `mmm-mode-ext-classes-alist` entries. You can take the example at the top of `mmm-erb.el`, as it definitely works for me. If it doesn't, create an issue at github, or just shoot me an email with details.

Comment: Works now, thank you. It was my mistake: I copied lines from "Usage" section of mmm-erb.el and removed lines i've copied from mmm readme. But as example in mmm-erb contains no `(setq mmm-global-mode 'maybe)` line, it didn't work for me.

Comment: I guess I forgot that it's not the default value. I'll see that it's added to the example.